# How to connect Raspberry Pi USB to a custom USB PCB?

Tags: pcb, usb, raspberry-pi

I'm designing a PCB that I wish to connect to a Raspberry Pi Zero W through USB, how should I approach that?

I have the inputs from the module (D+, D-, etc.) but to connect them to the Pi Zero, do I need to de-solder the Pi's USB connector and connect both USB ports through the pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exposed USB test pads on the bottom of the Raspberry Pi Zero. You can design your PCB to be mounted underneath the Zero and connect to the pads using pogo pins. This has been done before to make a [USB hub for the Zero](http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/is-zero4u-compatible-with-raspberry-pi-zero-w/):

[image: Zero4U USB hub for Raspberry Pi Zero]

As stated in the link, you may need to use a ferrite to protect the USB pins if you have a Zero W - the wireless can interfere with the USB connection.

Comment: so all I need is to connect the D+ and D- tests pads with pogo pins like in this picture? https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/0585/files/PiZeroConnections_large.jpg?14913446398312428817

Comment: And ground, of course!

Answer (score 0):

##### TL;DR

Use PCB mounted male micro USB connectors. Add the pads and solder the male connector on to your PCB.

---

A perfect example of this is the nComputing workspace hub (RX-HDX) which, internally, is just a Pi Zero W with a couple of additional PCBs that plug directly into the HDMI and the USB sockets of the Pi Zero.

The USB port of the Pi Zero, nearest to the mini HDMI connector, is used to provide additional power to the HDMI PCB. The other USB port is just a through connector for the power in.

The USB PCB uses two male micro USB PCB mounted connectors, like so:

[image: The internal PCBs of an nComputing device showing the male micro USB connectors]

This would seem to be the neatest solution for your project.

Note: The photo is just an illustration of a PCB mounted male micro USB connector. You could, of course, also make a small separate PCB just for the micro USB connectors, but I can't see the point.  Just add the male connector(s) to your PCB. As you seem to be interested only in the data lines, you could omit the pass-through connector for the power in, if you so wish.

I do not know why nComputing designed the boards this way and used two separate PCBs. I can only assume that the small PCB that converts the mini HDMI to full size HDMI was already used in a different product, so instead of creating a dual purpose HDMI/USB board, they just designed an additional USB PCB to be used in conjunction with the existing HDMI PCB, in order to reduce costs.

Admittedly, male micro USB PCB mounted connectors do not seem to be very common - I had a quick look on RS-online, and couldn't find any, but they clearly do exist (as the photo above shows). On Mouser, I only managed to find [vertically mounted connectors](https://www.mouser.co.uk/c/connectors/usb-connectors/?gender=Plug%20%28Male%29&mounting%20style=PCB%20Mount&product=Micro%20USB%20Type%20B%20Connectors):

[image: Vertical PCB mounted male micro USB connector]

Comment: So I need to design a separate PCB just for the connector, and connect it to the main PCB?

Comment: No, just add the pads and solder the male connector on to your PCB. The photo is just an illustration of a PCB mounted male micro USB connector. You could, of course make a small separate PCB just for the micro USB connectors, but I can't see the point. I do not know why nComputing did it this way and used two separate PCBs. I can only assume that the small PCB that converts the mini HDMI to full size HDMI was already used in a different product, so instead of creating a dual purpose HDMI/USB board, they just designed an additional USB PCB to be used in conjunction with the existing HDMI PCB.

Comment: That is not the most mechanically robust connector I have seen...